# How to match identifiers except when found within quotes?

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have the following string, and I want to extract all identifiers that start with a capital letter, **except** when found within quotes:

```
Match1
Match2(Match3("NoMatch1 a NoMatch2 blabla"), Match4)
meh<Match5>
```

In this case, `Match1`, `Match2`, `Match3`, `Match4`, and `Match5` should be caught, while `NoMatch1` and `NoMatch2` should be ignored since they are within a quoted string.

I can get the desired result using the JS regex. Link: [`(?<=^(\[^\"\]|\"\[^\"\]*\")*)(\b\[A-Z\]\w+\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/x2Vv7I/14), but all my attempts to convert this into a working Python regex have failed miserably. The error messages I've encountered so far:

```
( A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width
* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width
) A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width
* A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width
```

I have no clue whatsoever on how to fix this. Is this at all possible using Python regex? If so, what am I missing?

**Note**: I have no actual Python code yet, I have been trying this out on https://regex101.com thus far.

Comment: A simple approach can also be to use `(\b[A-Z]\w+\b)|(\"[^\"]*\")` and in the code filter out matches where the first group didn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following pattern:

```
\b[A-Z]\w+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nCAohU/1)**.

The trick is to use a positive Lookahead (which can have a non-fixed length, unlike the Lookbehind). So, we use the Lookahead to check for *pairs* of double quotations (because each opening quote would have a closing one). As long as the word to be matched is followed by an even number of double quotations (i.e., pairs), we know that it itself is *not* enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Note that this regex does not work in a case where the OP's does: if you have a capitalised word that is followed by a single unmatched `"`, it won't match whereas it would in the original.

Comment: @Grismar That is true. But then, the original pattern won't match a capitalized word when _preceded_ by a single unmatched `"`. The bottom line is that if you have a single `"` that is not part of a pair, the whole thing breaks down anyway and results become unpredictable. That's just a limitation of quotations (whether single or double) because unlike brackets/parentheses/braces, the opening and closing characters of quotations are the same char.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely - I think the solution is sound, just pointing it out for anyone that doesn't realise. They're not equivalent, but it's the right solution to use.

Comment: Good points. I'll be running this on valid C++, so I think I'm good. I'll deal with any special cases if I encounter them, this is close enough. Thanks!